# jQuery split is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
function showunit(){
    var unit = $("#Unit").val();
    var selected_unit = unit.split(', ');
    alert(selected_unit);
}
```

Unit values:

```
1,2
```

Anyone can please tell me why I am getting an error that unit.split is not function. How can I resolve that error?

Comment: Can you show the element with the ID of Unit ?

Comment: @MrMarlow I can show you output of $("#Unit").val() function.

Comment: what is `typeof unit`?

Comment: _1,2_  if unit values are pure `number` `split` will not work! but it will not happen since you're using `.val()` which returns string obviously! error might be elsewhere.

Comment: Good call, gurvinder - can you show result of alert(typeof unit) ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia I added unit values in question. for more information, you can check http://vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/Item. The Just select unit you will get an error in console.

Comment: [Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/w5ckkv87/), assuming your value is `1, 2` not `1,2`.

Comment: What page on that link can we view #Unit ?

Comment: I suppose you want the selected option values altogether as they are already appearing in array format. So I guess you need to do this `$("#Unit").val().join(",")` instead of `split`

Comment: @RushabhShah I selected unit, I got no error in the console. Can you share what browser version you are using?

Comment: Im voting to close this, as it [works](http://jsbin.com/tequjexahu/edit?output)